# A term related to cones and conical surfaces

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry

How the following body in a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$R(d;\phi) = \{v\in\mathbb{R}^n \mid \widehat{vd}<\phi, v\ne 0\}$$
is called (for some fixed nonzero vector $d$ and angle $\phi$, we can assume $\phi<\pi$)?

$\widehat{ab}$ here denotes the angle between vectors $a$ and $b$.

I feel it is related with cones and conical surfaces, but not sure about the precise term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to see that
$$R(d;\phi) = \{v \in \mathbb R^n \mid (v,d) > \cos(\phi) \, \|v\|\,\|d\|\}$$

In the special case $d = e_1$ and $\cos(\phi) = 2^{-1/2}$ you have
$$R(d;\phi) = \{v \in \mathbb R^n \mid 2^{-1/2} \, \|v\| < v_1 \}\\
= \{v \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|\hat v\| < v_1\},$$
where $\hat v = (v_2, \ldots, v_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. In convex optimization, the closure of this special $R(d;\phi)$ is called second-order cone.

Hence, one could call your set open, generalized second-order cone.

Comment: If I call it "open, generalized second-order cone" it won't help readers of my manuscript. It is easier to figure the shape from the formula itself rather than from your words. So these words are useless